# Sharing violation on path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some string to a file, and here is the code:

```
private static void WriteSelfDefinedFile(string msg)
    {
        ArrayList logTypes = SelfDefinedLogRule(msg);
        // New some StreamWriter here
        StreamWriter[] sws = new StreamWriter[selfDefinedLogFileName.Length];
        for(int i = 0;i<selfDefinedLogFileName.Length;i++)
        {
            sws[i] = new StreamWriter(selfDefinedLogDir + selfDefinedLogFileName[i], true);
            Debug.Log("111");

        }

        // It is writting here, not important for this question,I think.
        foreach(SelfDefinedLogType temp in logTypes)
        {
            int index = (int)temp;
            foreach (SelfDefinedLogType n in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SelfDefinedLogType)))
            {
                if(temp == n && sws[index]!=null)
                {
                    sws[index].WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":\t"+ msg);
                    break;
                }
                else if(sws[index] == null)
                {
                    LogError("File " + selfDefinedLogFileName[index] + " open fail");
                }
            }          
        }
        // Close the StreamWrite[] here
        for(int i=0;i<selfDefinedLogFileName.Length;i++)
        {
            sws[i].Close();
            Debug.Log("222");
        }

    }
```

When the client is sending msg to server or server replying some msg to client, this funtion will be called to write some message to some files.
And unity throws the IOException:Sharing violation on path D:\SelfDefinedLogs\SentAndReceiveMsg.txt, sometimes. I mean, it doesn't happened everytime I write.
I have closed all the opened streamWriter at the end of the funtion, but the problem still come up.I am really confused.I will be grateful if anybody gives some solutions to this problem.

Comment: Any code execution that means that `sws[i].Close();` doesn't execute (e.g. an exception in the `foreach`) will mean that the file won't be closed. Consider using a `finally` block and putting your `Close` / `Dispose` calls in there. Also consider using `sws[i]?.Dispose();` instead. Also consider using `Path.Combine`).

Comment: Short answer, you have the file open, don't do that. Long answer, as to why where or how its open, is an issue for you and debugging to make sure your code is logically working the way you want it to and fault tolerant

Comment: `else if(sws[index] == null)` I am 99.9% sure it isn't possible to enter that `else if`.

Comment: You should probably use `using` blocks for auto dispose the streams once not needed anymore. Are there maybe duplicate entries in `SelfDefinedFileName` so the same file is tried to be written to? For debugging you should probably wrap the entire code in a `try - catch` and set a breakpoint in the catch block and then examine where exactly the exception is thrown. Also make sure the file isn't open in another program ofcourse ;)

Comment: There is also [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) method, so you don't have to deal with streams

Comment: Can it happen that your method is called from different threads? Then it might be a concurrency issue.